# How to Open files in Other Directories in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, directory

I was wondering if anyone can show me how to open another file from another directory in python and then return to the default script

My Code:

```
    Bootstrap_location= 'C:\ProgramData\TERMINAL\Boot_Strp'
    Bootstrap_App_Loc=os.path.join(Bootstrap_location+"Terminal_Bootstrapper.py")
    from Bootstrap_App_Loc import Terminal_Bootstrapper.py
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Don't include the '.py' in import statements.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the path to the file if it is not already on the sys.path.  The module name is the filename without the '.py'

```
import sys
sys.path.append('C:\ProgramData\TERMINAL\Boot_Strp')
import Terminal_Bootstrapper
```